# rendered SVG elements not showing in browser

Tags: javascript, json, svg

I'm trying to write code in Js that will build an html page from JSON format. Everything works except for rendering SVG elements. The problem is this: the SVG element is in the html code, but the browser does not display it!
If you manually add some tag after the svg element in the inspector, for example `<br>`, then the svg will immediately appear on the screen.

Tried using createElementNS. In this case, it only works if there is nothing in JSON other than svg elements! As soon as you add for example img, then svg stops being displayed on the screen! I've already broken my head, I don't know what to do!

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg height="70" width="150">
    <polygon points="2,10 50,7 139,32 66,51"></polygon>
  </svg>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  function renderHtmlElements(data) {
    const element = document.createElement(data.tag);
    if (data.attributes) {
      Object.keys(data.attributes).forEach(key => {
        element.setAttribute(key, data.attributes[key]);
      });
    }
    if (data.children) {
      data.children.forEach(childData => {
        const childElement = renderHtmlElements(childData);
        element.appendChild(childElement);
      });
    }
    if (data.textNode) {
      element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.textNode));
    }
    return element;
  }

  // parent to insert the HTML
  const container = document.querySelector(".container");

  // data for the HTML in a JSON object
  const htmlData = {
    "tag": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "id": "L1",
      "class": "Labels"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "tag": "img",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "",
          "src": "",
          "width": "160",
          "height": "100"
        },
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "tag": "div",
        "attributes": {},
        "children": [
          {
            "tag": "svg",
            "attributes": {
              "width": "150",
              "height": "70"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "tag": "polygon",
                "attributes": {
                  "points": "2,10 50,7 139,32 66,51"
                },
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }

  // Create the HTML element from the JSON data and append it to the container
  const htmlElement = renderHtmlElements(htmlData);
  container.appendChild(htmlElement);
</script>

</html>
```

Next code dosn't work too..:

```
function renderHtmlElements(data) {
let element;
if (data.tag === "svg") {
  element = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", data.tag);
} else {
  element = document.createElement(data.tag);
}

if (data.attributes) {
  Object.keys(data.attributes).forEach(key => {
    if (data.tag === "svg") {
      element.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", key, data.attributes[key]);
    } else {
      element.setAttribute(key, data.attributes[key]);
    }
  });
}
if (data.children) {
  data.children.forEach(childData => {
    const childElement = renderHtmlElements(childData);
    element.appendChild(childElement);
  });
}
if (data.textNode) {
  element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data.textNode));
}
return element;
```

}

Comment: You must use createElementNS to create SVG elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Comment: Use the right namespace for the different elements. SVG namespace for SVG elements and `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` for HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
Need use setAttribute() instead setAttributeNS()